# How to sync sliders on qgraphicsview?

Tags: c++, qt

I have two qgraphicsviews, how do I keep their sliders in sync? That is, if I drag one slider (let's say horizontal) on one qgraphicsview, then it (the horizontal slider) changes accordingly on the other qgraphicsview.
example:

[image: example]

Answer (score 1):

Following code should sync them:

```
QGraphicsView leftView(leftScene);
QGraphicsView rightView(rightScene);

QObject::connect(leftView.horizontalScrollBar(), SIGNAL(valueChanged(int)), rightView.horizontalScrollBar(), SLOT(setValue(int));
QObject::connect(rightView.horizontalScrollBar(), SIGNAL(valueChanged(int)), leftView.horizontalScrollBar(), SLOT(setValue(int));

leftView.show();
rightView.show();
```

By the way if you are trying to show exactly the same thing in both views, you can use one scene for both of them.

Comment: thanks for the answer and advice! I will try!